# Connection Property is empty in Sybase Unwired Platform

Tags: eclipse, connection, sybase, sup

I'm trying to change connection profile to my mbo objects in SUP.
I created a new connection profile (sapn). I cannot use it. http://yadi.sk/d/yVjE1pBz21ZoM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the empty cell on the right of 'sapn' and you will be presented with a select containing the data sources you defined in the Mobile Workspace.